# Is the first row of Dataset<Row> which is created from a csv file equals to the first row in the file?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to remove header from the `Dataset<Row>` which is created with the data from csv file. There are bunch of ways to do it. 

So, I'm wondering whether the first row in `Dataset<Row>` is always equals to the first row in the file (from which the `Dataset<Row>` is created)?

Comment: You should just use the built-in CSV reader in Spark `val df = spark.read.csv("path", header=true)`

Comment: @Silvio that's for pyspark and the OP uses `Dataset<Row>` that's _unfortunately_ Java.

Comment: Silvio: Yes, I know that. I was curious to know what would be the first row after creating the Dataset from file. Answer from @Shankar addressed it.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read the files, the records in the RDD/Dataframe/Dataset are in the order as they were in the files. But if you perform any operation that requires shuffling the order changes.

So you can remove the first row as soon as reading the file and before any operation that requires shuffling.

The best option would be using `csv` data source as

```
spark.read.option("header", true).csv(path)
```

This will take the first row as a header and use it as column name.

Comment: Make sense. Thanks!